# Can multiple forms store their results in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have multiple Google forms with matching questions. Is it possible to keep the forms separate but see their results in the same Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

You can have them go to different sheets and then combine them in a third sheet with a formula like so:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("XYZk0274gRlmluCTfMbzbMQWKiAeq1va77X4","Mar-Apr-May!A2:D6");IMPORTRANGE("XYZahJZHSlhMGLSW_xA6ZBqNmt1I0ADo4N4M","Jun-Jul-Aug!A2:D4")},"select * where Col1<>''")
```

[Code source](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-ways-to-combine-multiple-sheets/)

Note that

- "XYZ…" is the key from a Sheet URL. You can also use the full URL. You will need to approve access between the sheets
- In "Mar-Apr-May!A2:D6" the part before the `!` is the name of the sheet tab, and "A2:D6" is the range of cells to import.
- `"select * where Col1<>''"` is filtering out blank columns

Comment: There are risks associated with this aporoach that are not detailed.  For example, IMPORTRANGE automatically checks for updates every hour.

Comment: I'll with ur code but  the result only comes out the header

Comment: `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kDMY8LCdWTG8UhTR5fPg-Rw_-ac8avbhgXkYbcxhefE/edit#gid=1016925214","ALPHA!A:C");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cqKyyFrCLIhk2K2xlNhZTeC8E2qGYZu-s64P0zYGbQc/edit#gid=315890450","BLUE!A2:C")}, "select * where Col1<>'' order by Col1")`

Comment: @JonFerson If Col1 is blank, it won't include the row. You should use a column that won't be blank. If that's not the issue, see if each IMPORTRANGE works by itself and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes-ish

You can definitely have the  responses from multiple Google forms go to the same spreadsheet however each form's results will be stored in a separate sheet (tab).

It is a simple matter to add another sheet that combines the form results.

## Formulae

If your form results are in columns A to F of **`Form Responses 1`** and **`Form Responses 2`**, use the following formula in another sheet to combine the results.

#### 1(a). QUERY

```
=QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A:F;
        'Form Responses 2'!A2:F},
        "where Col1 is not Null", 1)
```

- note that the first sheet starts at Row 1, but the second (third, fourth, etc.) start at Row 2 so the headings aren't duplicated.
- The sheet will dynamically update as form data is submitted.
- [QUERY function - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

#### 1(b). QUERY w/ Order by

- Assuming the first column is the timestamp, you could sort the data in descending order by that column:

```
=QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A:F;
        'Form Responses 2'!A2:F},
        "where Col1 is not Null
         Order by Col1 Desc", 1)
```

#### 2(a). FILTER

```
=LET(array,{'Form Responses 1'!A:F;
            'Form Responses 2'!A2:F},
     FILTER(array, INDEX(array,,1)<>""))
```

#### 2(b). FILTER w/ SORT

- If you plan to sort the data then with FILTER you should separate the header row from the SORT in the formula:

```
=LET(array,{'Form Responses 1'!A2:F;
            'Form Responses 2'!A2:F},
    {'Form Responses 1'!A1:F1;
     SORT(FILTER(array, INDEX(array,,1)<>""),1,0)})
```

## Specify Existing Spreadsheet

1. Click the kebab **More** button on the **Responses** tab 
   [image: Click the kebab more menu on the responses tab]
2. From the **More** menu, choose **Select destination for responses** 
   [image: Arrow pointing to the option 'Select destination for responses']
3. Choose the option **Select existing spreadsheet** and then the **Select** button. 
   [image: Arrow pointing to the option 'Select existing spreadsheet']
4. Select the Google spreadsheet where you want the responses. A new sheet will be inserted for each form.